# Get DataGridView ColumnHeaders values without scrolling the whole grid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I generate a DataGridView using the result of a query.
The query generates a LOT of columns (more than 75). Obviously the DataGridView  does not show all of them.

I wrote a small procedure that extracts data from the DataGridView and generates an Excel file ora .csv file.

What I find amusing is that both Excel and .csv are correctly generated EXCEPT for the column headers! I mean: ALL CELLS are written to the file EXCEPT for column headers.

I then discovered that if the DataGridView doesn't visualize the column headers it will not set their values.

So I wrote the following horrible code to scroll the DataGridView horizontally so that column headers are visualized in the DataGridView and extraction to Excel or .csv works:

```
Friend Sub ScrollTheGridToSeeColumnHeaders(ByRef dgvTheGrid As DataGridView)
  If dgvTheGrid.RowCount = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
  End If
  dgvTheGrid.SuspendLayout()
  For i32ScorriCol As Int32 = 0 To dgvTheGrid.ColumnCount - 1 Step dgvTheGrid.DisplayedColumnCount(True)
    dgvTheGrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = dgvTheGrid.Columns(i32ScorriCol).Index
    dgvTheGrid.Refresh()
  Next
  dgvTheGrid.ResumeLayout()
  dgvTheGrid.CurrentCell = dgvTheGrid(0, 0)
End Sub
```

This works, but effect to the user is really horrible (he sees the grid scrolling to the end and thinks he did some kind of bad mistake...).

Do you have a suggestion to do the trick without all these columns scrolling in such a horrible way?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the DataGridView bound to something like a DataSet?  Where does it get it's data?

Comment: DatagridView is unbound. It is constructed from data coming from a DataReader that read data from a SQL Server DB. The DataReader is closed when EndUser decides to do extraction.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an awful lot of unnecessary work.  In one of my applications, I have a datagridview, and I provide the user with the ability to "copy to excel".  The code is pretty simple.  A user selects all the rows they want from the datagridview (of course, the code could be tweaked to just select every single row), and they press "copy to excel", and it opens a new excel doc and pastes the entire selected datagridview in, headers and all.

Here's the code:

```
Try
    'Copy to the clipboard
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(Me.dgvTable.GetClipboardContent())
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Clipboard could not be accessed.  Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try

'Create excel objects
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

'Paste the stuff in
oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select()
oBook.Worksheets(1).Paste()
```

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Really: a very nice piece of code. But it doesn't solve my "problem": my grid contains more than 75 fields and I need to provide users the ability extract all of them. Selecting 75 columns and (may be) more than 1000 rows is not "user friendly" :-)

Comment: Instead of having the user select what rows/columns they want to copy to excel, why not do it programatically, and select them for the user?

Comment: In another part of my program I let users do what you say. The problem still remains if the user selects a sufficient number of fields to display: column headers are not reported to Excel until the grid displays them. There is another option: let user select columns on the grid, but this takes too long time to them.

Comment: What if you pasted twice? First, select the appropriate headers, and paste by doing oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select() then .Paste()... Then select what the user has selected and do oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Select and finally .Paste()?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, but I need to solve the problem about headers not being "refreshed": some grids I have need to be FullRowSelect and in such a case you can't select ColumnHeaders.